# How can one restrict the "open with" flow to single files?

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to prevent multiple file ids from being sent to my app when a user clicks open...

OR i would like my app removed from the open with when multiple files are selected.

Similar to the selection of multiple native Google documents.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently do this. Best you can do is handle it at your end. This could be achieved by either raising an error if you are sent with a multiple selection, or perhaps opening the first file and warning the user.